# .vmdk file is greyed out when I try to import from VMware Fusion 8 Mac OSX El Capitan

Tags: virtual-machine, osx-yosemite, vmware, vmware-fusion

I don't understand why my .vmdk file is greyed out when I try to import (import existing virtual machine) it from VMware Fusion 8? Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 3):

From installation method window, you are probably trying "Install from disc or image". Rather try "Create a custom virtual machine".

Comment: This was the issue for me. Should this answer be accepted for reaganRezvi's credit?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a new drive to the VM and edit the disc descriptor in the vmdk file manually. should do the trick